# Does every group have a generator?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Can't ask my question specifically because it's on a take-home test, but it's critical to my current proof that I'm able to pick a generator g from a group G, and I'm not sure if I can do that.

Comment: if you are claiming can every group be generated by a single element? then the answer is no. Just take any non-cyclic group. If you are looking for a generating set then the answer is yes.

Comment: It's probably a slippery slope on what you can and can't ask for a take home test. Have you tried asking your professor (or whoever assigned the test)? If it's a question about what you can assume, that's probably the best person to ask.

Comment: One reason of confusion is that the word "generator" is senseless. The good definition is that of "generating subset". It is then convenient informal language to call elements of generating subset "generators".

Comment: like cheating??

Answer (score 17):

Every group has a set of generators. Groups that have *one* generator are called cyclic. Not every group is cyclic.

Comment: I think that's enough to work with, thanks

Comment: A set of generators does not, however, mean that each individual group element is a single generator. @PeaceBlaster Indeed, we know that every group has a set of generators since the entire group is a "set of generators."

Comment: so that would mean that say, g^k*h^j would be necessary to make a given element, using potentially multiple generators to whatever powers to make a given element?

Comment: I really feel like this problem is supposed to be about a cyclic group, but it doesn't say so anywhere so I'm doing my best with what I have

Comment: A better terminology is "generating set," to avoid confusion. $\{g,h\}$ would be a generating set if there is no non-trivial subgroup of $G$ which contains $\{g,h\}$. Basically, every element of $G$ can be written as a "word" in $\{g,h,g,h^{-1}\}$ - for example: $ghg^{-1}hhh$. @PeaceBlaster

Comment: I'm curious. Doesn't this only hold for finite groups? For example what is the generating set of $\R$ with $+$ or $\R-{0}$ with $*$?

Comment: @avid19 It makes no sense to talk about "the generating set".  Groups generally have many different generating set, and every group $G$ is generated by $G$.

Comment: So $\mathbb{R}$ is generated by $\mathbb{R}$. Brilliant. :)

Comment: @avid19 Yes. You can find a smaller subset of $\mathbb R$. $\mathbb R$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$, so has a basis $\{v_i\}_{i\in I}$ over $\mathbb Q$. Then the set of values $$\left\{\frac{1}{n!}v_i\mid i\in I,n\in\mathbb N\right\}$$ is a generating set. Technically, not "smaller" in the sense of cardinality, I suppose.

Comment: What is missing for infinite groups, in general, is minimal sets of generators. That is, it is not always true that there is a generating set $X$ such that no subset of $X$ is a generating set. @avid19

Comment: Shouldn't it mean groups that have *at least one generator* are cyclic?