# Cyclic groups and other groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Ok So I know that a cyclic group is a group that is generated by a single element like $\large{(Z_n,+)}$.

Now I was wondering that if every group has a generator , and I found that the answer is yes in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208416/does-every-group-have-a-generator).

However, This answer doesn't make sense. He is saying that every group has a set of generators and a group that has only one generator is cyclic.

Does that mean $\large{(Z_7,+)}$ is not cyclic for instance because both $1$ and $3$ are both generators of $\large{Z_7}$. But here in this [website](http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/abstract-algebra-1/cyclic/cyclic.html), they state that $\large{(Z_7,+)}$ is a cyclic group.

So in Summary here is my questions

(Question 1)

Is it true that if a group has more than one generator then it is not cyclic ?

(Question 2)

I want to see an example where a group has a set of generators not necessarily a single element !

I think that it is ok to have a cyclic group that is generated by more than one element as long as they are single elements, but how can we have a generator which is not a single element, I am really confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question $1$:**

No, that is not true.  The statement you are looking for is that if a group cannot be generated by a *single element* then it is not cyclic.  In other words, if there does not exist a $g \in G$ such that $G = \{ g^n \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, then $G$ is not cyclic.  Contrapositively, $G$ is cyclic if we can find a $g \in G$ such that $G = \{g^n \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.  But the wording here is subtle: notice in particular that we don't specify that $g$ be unique!  So $\mathbb{Z}_7$ is indeed cyclic even though both $1$ and $3$ generate it.

**Question 2:**

- The example that immediately comes to mind is the dihedral group of order $2n$, which is the group of symmetries of a regular $n$-gon.  This group is *not* cyclic, but it can be generated by $2$ elements: $R$ and $F$, where $R$ is a rotation of $\displaystyle \frac{2\pi}{n}$ radians about the center, and $F$ is any reflection over a line of symmetry.  To keep things simple, confirm this for a triangle or a square, and then try generalizing.
- Another example is the Klein-$4$ group $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$.  This group is not cyclic, but it can be generated by two elements, for example, $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$ as you can check.
- A rather complicated example is that of $S_p$ for some prime $p$.  This is the group of permutations on $p$ elements.  This group can be generated by any $2$-cycle together with any $p$-cycle.

Comment: Ok for the Klein-4 group, How can $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ generate the group ?

we have $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$ in the group. Now if I multiply $(0,1)(1,0)$ I get $(0,0)$. But how do I get $(1,1)$ ?

Comment: Careful!  The group operation is addition modulo $2$, so $(0, 1) + (1, 0) = (1, 1)$.

Comment: And of course we already have $(0, 1)$ and $(1, 0)$.  To get $(0, 0)$, we simply take $(0, 1) + (0, 1) = (0, 2) = (0, 0)$.

Comment: hmmm, ok so $(0,1) + (1,0) = (1,1)$ and $(0,1) + (1,0) + (0,1) + (1,0) = (1,1) + (1,1) = (0,0)$ hmm that make sense ! Thanks a ton!

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Comment: Athough it's off topic, Can you give me a very simple example of a free group. I am struggling to understand this topic

Comment: @alkabary, I wish I could help, but unfortunately I haven't yet encountered free groups.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: A group $G$ is *cyclic* if and only if $G$ can be generated by one element.  This element does not have to be unique.    So $(\mathbb{Z}_7,+)$ is indeed cyclic.

Question 2:  ($\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2,+)$ is not cylic.  It is of order 4, yet no element has more than order 2.

Comment: What are the set of generators of $Z_2 \times Z_2$ ?

Comment: Three Possibilities:  $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$  or $\{(1,0),(1,1)\}$ or $\{(0,1),(1,1)\}.$

Comment: A good exercise for you to work out on your own is to  prove any cyclic group is Abelian.   Then take it a step further and show that any cyclic group is isomorphic to $\{\mathbb{Z}_n,+)$ for some $n$ or is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z},+).$

Comment: @mattbiesecker Those are the minimal generating sets. You could also take any subset containing any of those.

Comment: @DerekHolt.  Thanks. Getting sloppy in my old age.